# Custom timestamp to mysql database on shared server using php

Tags: php, mysql

If you're going to judge this question as lacking details or being off-topic, please do not bother. Anyway, I have a website on a shared server. I am trying to insert data into a database with a timestamp defaulted to Africa/Cairo or +2 GMT but I am failing to achieve this. The time I get is CST no matter what I try. I used Now(), I changed the timezone, I even changed "date" in phpmyadmin to tinytext as my last resort. So help please. What is that code? I have searched everywhere on this website and it seems everyone is using their "servers" and not shared servers when giving answers.

Comment: Please provide some example code of what you are trying to do. It is really quite hard for anyone to provide assistance unless you provide the right details and context that this question is seriously lacking

Comment: Changing the format in the database isn't going to be of much help. If you're on a shared server you would use `date_default_timezone_set(<name of timezone here>);` in your PHP scripts.

Comment: [*"If you're going to judge this question as lacking details or being off-topic, please do not bother."*](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34181126/1). Wrong attitude. Not to mention missing relevant code.

Comment: try this also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 1):

At the begin of your php file, use this config set :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
```

Replace Europe/Paris by your own with this list : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thank you J. Grunder. Thanks for ignoring that "attitude". I have got it to work with that answer!

Comment: It is an attitude you seem to have no matter where you are @Samuellong

Comment: They are right Samuel Long, I could give you this answer because I encounter similar problem few weeks ago and I understand your issue. But someone that don't, he won't understand what you need, and that's why DavidWatts asked more information to you. Next time, ask a more detailed question from the begin to be sure you'll have an adapted answer.